# selenium web scraping Code is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrap data from the page which get opens by clicking these quest no-8526724 of the table but the click is not working. quest no is getting printed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the website in the browser
driver.get('https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787')

# Wait for the table to load
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'table_id')))

# Find all the quest numbers in the table
quest_numbers = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table//tbody//tr//td[2]')

# Click on each quest number and print the resulting page
for quest_number in quest_numbers:
    quest_number_text = quest_number.text
    print(quest_number_text)
    current_url = driver.current_url
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", quest_number)

    WebDriverWait(driver,40).
    until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'posting-second- 
    header'))) 
    page_source = driver.page_source
    print('Quest Number:', quest_number_text)
    print('Page Source:', page_source)
    time.sleep(2) 
    # Go back to the table
    driver.back()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried looping throw <tr> and clicking on <a> tag?

Comment: yes, but sometimes it works and then it doesn't.

Comment: What error do you get when it doesn't work? did you debug any of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use their Rest API instead:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# important: The Referer should be your URL:
headers = {
    "Referer": "https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787"
}


api_url = "https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/browse_posting/"
project_url = "https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id={project_id}&next_project_id=&prev_project_id="

params = {
    "search_id": "",
    "postings_since_last_login": "",
    "draw": "1",
    "columns[0][data]": "render_my_posting",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "false",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "render_post_date",
    "columns[1][name]": "",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "false",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "render_project_id",
    "columns[2][name]": "",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "render_category_search_string",
    "columns[3][name]": "",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "render_name",
    "columns[4][name]": "",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[5][data]": "bid_date_str",
    "columns[5][name]": "",
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[5][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[5][search][value]": "",
    "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[6][data]": "render_city",
    "columns[6][name]": "",
    "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[6][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[6][search][value]": "",
    "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[7][data]": "render_county",
    "columns[7][name]": "",
    "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[7][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[7][search][value]": "",
    "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[8][data]": "state_code",
    "columns[8][name]": "",
    "columns[8][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[8][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[8][search][value]": "",
    "columns[8][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[9][data]": "render_owner",
    "columns[9][name]": "",
    "columns[9][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[9][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[9][search][value]": "",
    "columns[9][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[10][data]": "render_solicitor",
    "columns[10][name]": "",
    "columns[10][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[10][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[10][search][value]": "",
    "columns[10][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[11][data]": "posting_type",
    "columns[11][name]": "",
    "columns[11][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[11][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[11][search][value]": "",
    "columns[11][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[12][data]": "render_empty",
    "columns[12][name]": "",
    "columns[12][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[12][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[12][search][value]": "",
    "columns[12][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[13][data]": "render_empty",
    "columns[13][name]": "",
    "columns[13][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[13][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[13][search][value]": "",
    "columns[13][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[14][data]": "render_empty",
    "columns[14][name]": "",
    "columns[14][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[14][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[14][search][value]": "",
    "columns[14][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[15][data]": "render_empty",
    "columns[15][name]": "",
    "columns[15][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[15][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[15][search][value]": "",
    "columns[15][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[16][data]": "project_id",
    "columns[16][name]": "",
    "columns[16][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[16][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[16][search][value]": "",
    "columns[16][search][regex]": "false",
    "start": "0",
    "length": "25",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "_": "1686072936017",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

out = []
for i in data["data"]:
    project_id = i["project_id"]
    u = project_url.format(project_id=project_id)
    print(f'Opening {u}...')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    # print some sample data from the page
    print(soup.h1.text)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8526724&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 22408 3000 E & FOOTHILL RD CURVE, TWIN FALLS HD 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8529878&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 24192 SH-75, Ohio Gulch Road Intersection 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8534098&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 23815 FY24 D6 STRIPING 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8536176&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 21842, I-84, FY23 D4 Interstate Striping 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8539402&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 20592 / 20482 SH-3, CDA RV BR to I-90, SH-97, HARRISON BR to WHISTLE RD 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8539418&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 23474 US-20; EXIT 343 INTERCHANGE 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8544737&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 23791, FY24 D1 STRIPING 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8544742&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 20487 FY24 D1 BRIDGE REPAIR 

Opening https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/util/get_posting/?current_project_id=8554006&next_project_id=&prev_project_id=...
Key No. 24249 SH-11 PIERCE TO GRANGEMONT ROADWAY REPAIR
```

Comment: see I want to scrap the page data that will get open after clicking on quest no-8526724. Not from table

Comment: @SHUBHAMSHEKHAR20GCEBCS091 Yes, the code does that. Getting the `<h1>` from the page when you click on Quest